# Why Return value in C limits to 0 to 256

Tags: c, return-value

Here are the simple programs in C that `returns` different values

**program : 1**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hey I am returning the value\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**program 2:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hey I am returning the value\n");
    return 255;
}
```

**program 3:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hey I am returning the value\n");
    return 258;
}
```

When I examine the return value of C program after the execution of it using the command `echo $?` in `ubuntu` it gives me ,

for program 1 : `0`

for program 2 : `255`

for program 3 :  `2`

After the value `256` ,it again returns`1` and so on...

Why this cycle happens?

Comment: I suspect the shell variable is only 8-bit.

Comment: Only the lower 8 bits of the exit status are used, yes. `wait()` and related functions store the status and other information (like if and what signal killed a process if it didn't exit normally) in the other bits of the int they save the exit status information in.

Comment: then, for windows kernel ? @Shawn

Comment: @ASWIN: On Microsoft Windows, I believe it is recommended to also only use values in the range `0` to `255`, because at least one value outside that range is reserved for a special purpose by the operating system. According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess), the value `259` is reserved to indicate that the process is still running.

Comment: For Linux, see [POSIX return - EXIT STATUS](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/return.html) (return should be an 8-bit unsigned value) `stdlib.h` defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` as `0` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `main()` is equivalent to the `status` argument to `exit()`. The [C specification](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4) only documents three values of the exit status:

- `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `0` (which are typically the same), meaning that the program terminated successfully.
- `EXIT_FAILURE`, meaning that the program ended unsuccessfully.

The treatment of any other value is implementation-defined.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/exit.html) further specifies that only the least significant 8 bits will be available to a waiting process. The `wait()` family of functions put this in the low-order 8 bits of the termination status, using the other bits to hold flags that can be accessed with macros such as `WIFSIGNALED()` (which indicates whether the process terminated due to receiving a signal rather than calling `exit()`).

Comment: Turns out POSIX lets you get the full exit status, not just 8 bits, if you use `waitid()`, or a  `SIGCHLD` handler using siginfo, instead of the traditional `wait()`/`waitpid()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because traditionally many operating systems and C implementations used a single byte (8 bits) to store the exit status of a process, the range 0 to 255 is frequently referenced. Since a single byte can store values in the range of 0 to 255 (2<sup>8</sup> - 1), this range came to be widely accepted as the standard for expressing exit statuses.

The exit status is still expressed using a single byte in contemporary systems, particularly those based on Unix-like operating systems. The return value range from `main()` is not subject to any specific restrictions, nevertheless, according to C, as it returns `int`. The operating system and runtime environment must determine how to interpret the return value and manage it.